# Не работает цикл for на HTML коллекцию.

Tags: javascript, html5

Я только учу JS, поэтому если допустил какую-то элементарную ошибку, которая привела к проблеме, то заранее извините. 
В общем, у меня есть следующая переменная:

```
let deleteIcons = document.getElementsByClassName('material-icons');
```

В ней собраны иконки удаления элемента списка, который я генерирую. Цель - реализовать удаление элемента при клике на иконку. Для того, чтобы повесить обработчик событий и отслеживать клик по каждой иконке, мне нужно сначала перебрать коллекцию, чтобы на каждой итерации добавлять событие. 
Ну а теперь мы подошли к сути проблемы:

```
for (let i = 0; i < deleteIcons.length; i++) {
    console.log(deleteIcons[i]);
};
```

при моей попытке перебрать массив ничего не происходит (консольлогом я просто проверяю работоспособность кода). Вообще ничего, ни ошибки, ни ворнинга, по мнению редактора с консолью девтулс всё нормально. Когда я пытаюсь перебрать что-то другое, то никаких проблем.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
};
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы и извините, если проблема тривиальная, а решение очевидно.

Comment: Возможно, когда вы выполняете `document.getElementsByClassName('material-icons')` элементов еще нету. Приведите полный пример кода, который бы воспроизводил проблему.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не когда выполняется getElementsByClassName, а даже когда результат проверяет, потому коллекция живая возвращается

Comment: Это выполняется в самом начале, ну почти. Я делал проверочный коносоль.лог и получал массив с названием HTML Collection, мог его открыть и посмотреть, а самое главное, он имел length: 3. Но после Вашего комментария я законсолил на это же месте не сам массив, а сразу его длину. И получил 0, что довольно странно для меня. Дальше я перенёс цикл в коде на место после вызова функции, генерирующей список - всё заработало. Попробую я всё это переварить теперь. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает **живую** коллекцию, то есть любое изменение в DOM, сразу отображается в коллекции.

Это значит, что получив коллекцию до того как добавились элементы, после их добавления - в коллекции все равно будут актуальные данные, но перебор коллекции до и после добавления элементов будет отличаться:

```js
var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
console.log('tests.length:', tests.length);

tests[0].className = 'without-test';
console.log('tests.length:', tests.length);
```

```css
#container div::after {
  content: attr(class);
}

#container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container .test {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```